# root mean square (RMSD) of two datasets

Tags: python-2.7

I'm dragging along in python, learning so slow but making progress.  Have hit a wall, and don't even know where to start on this.

I have other scripts that get me to where I am now:   two output CSV files with multiple rows containing 4 numbers each.  The first number is an identifier integer, the other three are X, Y, Z coordinates.

Now the OTHER file is the same thing, with the same set of identifier integers, but a different set of X, Y, Z coordinates.

For each identifier integer, I want to calculate the RMSD between the X,Y,Z.  In other words, I think I need to do (X2-X1)^2 + (Y2-Y1)^2 + (Z2-Z1)^2 then take the square root of that.  This will give me a float as an output answer, which I'd like to write into an output file of two columns:  one with the the identifier integer, and the second is the output from this script.

I actually have no idea where to start on this one..  I've never had to work with two files at once.   Gah!

thanks so much!!

sorry I have no script to even start here!